# Subdomains with Wordpress multisite and Amazon EC2

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2

I have a a WordPress multisite install (using subdomains, not subfolders) running on EC2 (with Cloudflare for DNS). It is working good.
I am starting a new project that I want to setup a subdoamin for that is not using the multisite install. I have been trying for a few days to get it to work, but i cannot get it to stop sending trafic to wordpress (which is telling me there is not site set up (I hae set nothing up in wordpress as this project has its own site / code that I want to keep seperate)
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you?

Comment: after workingon it more,I am 99% sure that the server is set up right and its wordpress multisite thats causing the issue. is there a way to tell wordpress to ignore a subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

After quite a while of banging my head agenst the wall I figgured it out.
How I got it to work was I went into the Apache config file (httpd.conf) and changed the server name to a fake address, then wet into vhosts.conf and created a virtual host for every site on the server, including the main one (that had been listed in the main conf) and the wildcard (for multisite).
I made sure the wildcard was listed LAST. After restarting the server it worded like a charm.